# I don't find the folder and file app/appkernel.php in symfony 4 ton enable Easy Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

To install EasyAdmin Bundle, I need to enable the bundle in app/AppKernel.php but I don't find it ! Please help !

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 4 introduced a new composer plugin called flex:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html

Install EasyAdminBundle with `composer req admin` will automatically configure defaults and
also add the bundle to bundles.php file.

No more manual steps required afterwards, just add the new file to git.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony4 there's no app/ folder by default, the structure is different from previous Symfony releases.

You have to add your bundle to `config/bundles.php`. The kernel class should be in `src/Kernel.php`.

To learn more: http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-directory-structure.html

Comment: But I'm lost ! In my file bundle.php, easyadmin is enable. In the doc of Symfony, we have a new class EasyAdminBundle in a array ($bundles) and where do I have to add it ?

Comment: The `src/Kernel.php` class is in charge of loading the bundles from that array. Look at the `Kernel` method `registerBundles()`.